# Slider / Range control in Orbeon Forms

Tags: forms, slider, range, orbeon

Is there an option in **Orbeon Forms** or a work-around how an Slider/Range control  for numbers can be implemented? Per my knowledge, it is supported by XForms standard, but there is no Orbeon Forms-specific control. Any thoughts or advice how to implement it in the proper way?

I see https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2658, but it's still open.

Answer (score 0):

There is a legacy slider (range) control, but it is quite obsolete. RFE [#2658](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2658) is not implemented yet, as you have noticed, and the right answer is to implement it.